# Export function to another class with default export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have two class `Orders.js` and `api.js`. i need to call a `ShowAlertWithDelay` in `api.js` but since i already have a default export `mapStateToProps` im unable to use another export. below is the code

```
Orders.js

class Order extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    getOrders: []
      }


ShowAlertWithDelay = () => {
ShowToast("location",3,5000);
  };

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
getOrders: state.User.getOrders ? state.User.getOrders : [],
deliveredorder: state.User.deliveredorder ? state.User.deliveredorder : [],
userData: state.User.userData ? state.User.userData : false,
selectedTabdeliverOrder: state.User.selectedTabdeliverOrder ? state.User.selectedTabdeliverOrder : false
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Order);


api.js

class Api {
if(resp.data.RouteCompleted == 206){

//Need to call ShowAlertWithDelay(); here

}
}
export default Api;
```

Comment: pls Improve your code

Comment: im new to react native. please do help with this

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to create a new file to export ShowAlertWithDelay
ShowAlertWithDelay.js

```
export const ShowAlertWithDelay = () => {
ShowToast("location",3,5000);
  };
```

in Orders.js and api.js

```
import {ShowAlertWithDelay}  from './ShowAlertWithDelay.js'
```

When you use "export default" then import like this

```
import ShowAlertWithDelay  from './ShowAlertWithDelay.js'
```

Comment: isn't there a way to call in Orders.js itself?

Answer (score 0):

you can index your Orders.js by creating index.js in the same directory, but you have "ShowAlertWithDelay" independent from Orders class

Orders.js

```
export const ShowAlertWithDelay =() =>{
  ShowToast("location",3,5000)
}
export class Order extends Component {
  //
}
```

index.js

```
export default { Orders } from './Orders.js'
export { ShowAlertWithDelay as Something } from './Orders.js'
```